# SQL Unpivot in Mode

Tags: sql, unpivot

Does anyone know whether the pivot and unpivot commands work or not in Mode Analytic's version of SQL?

Comment: Do you mean this one? https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-pivot-table/

Comment: I saw that, but I was wanting to use the actual Unpivot command and not a cross join.

Comment: If in the official documentation they use Joins instead of Pivot - it is more likely they do not support it :)

Comment: Okay, that's disappointing. Thank you for the help!